# Does MIPS assembly language have a library for all the set of instructions?

Tags: mips, mars-simulator

I have googled the following question and nothing close to a library for MIPS seemed to pop up. I have only managed to find university textbooks and would appreciate it if someone would share the link to a MIPS library site.

Comment: What do you mean by a "library"? If you mean an instruction set _reference_, then yes. It's called _MIPS32™ Architecture For Programmers Volume II: The MIPS32™ Instruction Set_

Comment: Sorry for the confusion Michael, and yes, that is what I meant: a library reference for the language. The appendix to the referred book was the closest I could find to a library reference. I was expecting the site to look like a python library reference page similar to this one https://docs.python.org/3/library/

Comment: Well, official instruction set references often come in the form of PDF documents. So there's the PDF that I mentioned in my first comment.